# Do I use the command "sum" in this situation?

Tags: mysql

I want to select from the table, results of a soccer game comparing the Home Team Score against Away Team Score and count it all together, as below:

- If Home Team Score is `>` Away Team Score = `Win`
- If Less `<` Away Team Score = `Loss`
- If Equal `=` Away Team Score = `Draw`

I have 2 columns that I want to use: `hometeamscore` and `awayteamscore`.

I know this code bellow count only one column:

`SELECT sum(hometeamscore) FROM tablename`

What can I do to know how many win, loss and draw the Home has in PHP?

Eg:

```
Game1: Home Team 3 - 0 Away Team
Game2: Home Team 2 - 0 Away Team
Game3: Home Team 1 - 1 Away Team
Game4: Home Team 3 - 2 Away Team
```

Result:

```
Win = `2`
Loss = `1`
Draw = `1`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In question table structure is not provided, but as per your given details your table may look like this.

```
CREATE TABLE score (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    hometeamscore TINYINT,
    awayteamscore TINYINT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)  ENGINE=INNODB;



INSERT score (hometeamscore,awayteamscore) values 
(3,0),(2,0),(1,1),(1,5);
```

And you need to use 3 saperate queries to get Win, Loss and Drow result respectively as below:

```
SELECT count(id) as Win FROM score where hometeamscore > awayteamscore;

SELECT count(id) as Loss FROM score where hometeamscore < awayteamscore;

SELECT count(id) as Drow FROM score where hometeamscore = awayteamscore;
```

Answer (score 2):

The results cannot be get by one query but we can use `UNION` of mysql to get it. You can get the results as follows:-

```
SELECT CONCAT('Win:- ', count(id)) as result FROM `scores` WHERE `hometeamscore` > `awayteamscore`
UNION
SELECT CONCAT('Draw:- ',count(id)) as result FROM `scores` WHERE `hometeamscore` = `awayteamscore`
UNION
SELECT CONCAT('Loss:- ',count(id)) as result FROM `scores` WHERE `hometeamscore` < `awayteamscore`
```

Comment: Yes, This is the answer if you want all result once in concatenated format. use `UNION` to combine result.

Answer (score 2):

This would also:

```
SELECT Result,COUNT(*) AS 'Total' FROM
     (SELECT 
            CASE WHEN hometeamscore > awayteamscore THEN 'Win'
            WHEN hometeamscore = awayteamscore THEN 'Draw'
            WHEN hometeamscore < awayteamscore THEN 'Loss' 
                 END AS Result
     FROM score) v 
GROUP BY result;
```

Comment: yes this one also works but most likely the most slow one also.. As the group by is on a "calculated" column which never can be indexed.. So the group by needs to scan and process all table/subquery resultset records in this query..

Comment: Thanks @RaymondNijland. I'll take note of that :)